# Eclipse: missing menu option to create new Remote C/C++ Project

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-rse

I am running Eclipse CDT Luna SR 1 (version 4.4.1) and have properly installed Remote System Explorer End-User Runtime and Remote system Explorer User Actions packages (both version 3.7.0). I can browse to a remote system and even create a link to a remote folder through RSE using SSH, but I cannot create a new Remote C++ Project as the Luna documentation describes [here](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.ptp.rdt.doc.user%2Fhtml%2Freference%2Fremote_properties_paths.html). The menu options in the manual simply do not exist. Is it necessary to install the RSE server somewhere first? That wouldn't make a lot of sense, since RSE can use local providers. Any help appreciated.